# ionic footer with toolbar removing extra spacing

Tags: ionic-framework, toolbar, footer

[image]I have created a full size button inside ion footer in a ion toolbar and the code looks like below

```
<ion-footer class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar style="--background:white">
    <ion-buttons>
      <ion-button (click)="continue()" color="secondary" fill="solid" class="sb-block-button">Save</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

however there is a gap on the right side in the footer. i do not want that and failed to remove it. what shoudl be done? here is how it looks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I belive you have set up some CSS for the button but seems not working well.
First, the button is not in the middle, so add some CSS here:

```
.sb-block-button {
    ......
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Second, button length may not be wide enough. So adjust the width/margins at the same place. You may do it yourself.
Hope it works.

Comment: well not really the answer and the css just has this : .sb-block-button {
    width: 315px;
    height: 40px;
}

looking at the inspector i see the button inside ion-buttons is left aligned by default, and i am failing to bring it to center